# SQL Server backup issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise on Windows Server 2008 x64. I want to run daily job at mid-night every day to make full backup of database. Any reference document to follow for a newbie of this topic?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

I am NOT a great fan of maintenance plans in SQL Server and have heard of so many issues with them on the forums. If you are open to new ideas, have you looked into regular T-SQL scripts for managing the maintanence tasks instead of MP. Ola Hallengren has some excellent scripts and am currently using them in 3 of my servers and they work great. The quality of code is vouched by many SQL Server MVPs too. I know this offtopic on what you asked but wanted to throw in another option. You can find the scripts @ http://ola.hallengren.com/

Ola has created some documetation also on this and it will be easy for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a Maintenance Plan.  Maintenance Plans in SQL Server can perform a variety of scheduled maintenance tasks for you on a schedule you specify.  You can create a maintenance plan which will back up your databases using the [Maintenance Plan Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189036.aspx) in SQL Management Studio.